# website not centered in firefox/chrome

Tags: css, html, firefox, google-chrome, widescreen

i am having a problem with my website on Widescreens on Firefox/Chrome. It's not centred for some reason, margin: 0 auto; is not working either. The website looks fine on normal screens or even wide screens with lower res but on 1900x1200 the content is not centered for some reason. However the website looks fine on IE 9 at 1900x1200. 
Here is the code:

jsfiddle.net/hXskH/

Any clues?

Comment: can you show me the live url of your website..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For it to be centered you need to add a width along with that `margin: 0 auto;` Most common width is 960px;

```
#main {
padding-bottom: 300px;
margin:0 auto;
position: relative;
width: 960px;
}
```

Comment: if I used width 960, the content will center however the pictures will go under each other and  I need them to be on the same line.

Comment: even If I set it to 1200 the result is the same.

Comment: it looks like it works on my screen when i usen width: 70%; but its missing up the other screens that looked good until now

Comment: @SarahMcLachlane your real width needs to be 1254px for the elements to stay in their place. Here's the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hXskH/5/

Answer (score 0):

You have not set width for #main, so as it is block level it has occupied full width ie 100%.

Set the width for element.

```
#main {
padding-bottom: 300px;
margin:0 auto;
width:<your-width>;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: mm even If I set it to 1200 the result is the same.